# Prove $\operatorname{div}(A \circ f \circ A^{-1}) (p) = \operatorname{div}(f)(A^{-1}p)$ with $A \in \operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vector-analysis

Let $A \in \operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ a continuously differentiable vector field. We define the vector field $f_A := A \circ f \circ A^{-1}$

Prove that:

1. $\operatorname{div}(f_A) (p) = \operatorname{div}(f)(A^{-1}p)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R^3}$
2. $\operatorname{rot}(f_A) (p) = \operatorname{rot}(f)(A^{-1}p)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R^3}$, if $A\in \operatorname{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$

**How I tried solving it**

*by brute force*:

$\operatorname{div}(f_A) (p)$ = ($\partial_1 A_{1,}(f_1(A_{1,}^{-1})) + \partial_2 A_{2,}(f_2(A_{2,}^{-1})) + \partial_3 A_{3,}(f_3(A_{3,}^{-1})))(p)$
However I do not really know how one continues from here.

*By using the definition*

Our textbook defines $\operatorname{div}(f)(p) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h^3} 
 \int_{\partial(p+[0,h]^3)} f \cdot d\vec{n}$

Similary  $\operatorname{rot}(f)(p) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2} 
 \int_{\partial B_r(p)} f \cdot d\vec{s}$

These definitions seem very technical so I am not sure how they should be used.

Your help is greatly appreciated since I don't even know where to start.

Comment: The integral definitions are indeed technical and the problem is that the square (shouldn't it be cube?) used in the definition of divergence gets skewed when applying $A$.  - But at least the sphere used for rotation is mapped to a sphere of equal radius and orientation!

Comment: You are right. Thanks or pointing it out. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the divergence.**

Applying the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), the [Fréchet dérivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) of $f_A$ at $p$ is
$$f_A^\prime(p)=A^\prime[(f \circ A^{-1})(p)] \circ f^\prime(A^{-1}(p)) \circ \left(A^{-1}\right)^\prime(p).$$

As $A$ and $A^\prime$ are linear applications, their Fréchet derivatives at any point are themselves. Hence $A^\prime[(f \circ A^{-1})(p)]=A$ and $\left(A^{-1}\right)^\prime(p)= A^{-1}$ which implies
$$f_A^\prime(p)=A \circ f^\prime(A^{-1}(p)) \circ A^{-1}.$$

As for any $h: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ continuously differentiable, $\operatorname{div}(h)(p) = \operatorname{Tr}(h^\prime(p))$ you get

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{div(f_A)}(p) &= \operatorname{Tr}(A \circ f^\prime(A^{-1}(p)) \circ A^{-1}) = \operatorname{Tr}(A \circ A^{-1} \circ f^\prime(A^{-1}(p)))\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}(f^\prime(A^{-1}(p))) = \operatorname{div}(f)(A^{-1}(p))
\end{align}$$

**For the curl equality**

Use the equality
$$\operatorname{div}(X_0 \wedge F) = - \operatorname{rot}F \cdot X_0$$ where $X_0$ is any constant vector field and the identity above for $\operatorname{div}$.

Comment: $\left(A^{-1}\right)^\prime(p)= A^{-1}$ makes total sense, but how does $A^\prime[(f \circ A^{-1})(p)]=A$. I understand that $A^\prime[(f \circ A^{-1})(p)]=A[(f \circ A^{-1})(p)]$. But then how does $A[(f \circ A^{-1})(p)] = A$. How do you "get rid" of the $f$ in the expression.

Comment: This is because the Fréchet derivative of a linear map $x \mapsto A(x)$ at any point $p$ is the linear map itself $h \mapsto [A^\prime(p)](h) = A(h)$. Which is denoted by $A^\prime(p) = A$. Remember that $A^\prime$ is a linear map for which the codomain is a vector space of linear maps!

Comment: ah yes of course. Thanks for clarifying